# Statement running regardless of If Statement

Tags: php, file-upload, if-statement

The 'unlink()' method is executed even though no images have been uploaded, why is this and how can I fix it?

```
If (isset($_FILES["image"]["name"])) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageUp"]["tmp_name"],
        "C:/xampp/htdocs/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    //if (file_exists($delete)) {
        unlink($delete);
    }
    else {
    $img = $data['row']->image_name;
    }
//}
```

Comment: Where does the value of `$delete` come from?

Comment: well, means `$_FILES["image"]["name"]` is set?

Comment: What is $delete ?? You have not explained about that. What does $delete contains ??

Comment: $delete contains a directory and a name for an image

Comment: `$delete` is not the destination file `C:/xampp/htdocs/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]`. Am I right?

Comment: What's with all the vote downs? @Tomás : actually it is.

Comment: @Grzegorz Oledzki : what did you edit?

Comment: @Azieb Assres He changed `runinng` to `running` in the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
isset($_FILES["image"]["name"]
```

will always be set even if you upload a file or not. `isset` checks whether the thing is set or not. So it will always be `true`.

So you need to change your code :

```
if (isset($_FILES["image"]["name"]) && !empty($_FILES["image"]["name"])) {
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageUp"]["tmp_name"],
    "C:/xampp/htdocs/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
//if (file_exists($delete)) {
    unlink($delete);
} else {
    $img = $data['row']->image_name;
}
```

Please try with this. Hope this helps :)

Comment: This works, and the funny thing is my original code was if ($_FILES["image"]["name"] != "")

Comment: I was downvoted too! I dont know why and I wrote a valid response like yours! Lets upvote ourselves Sabari

Answer (score 0):

According to the  [php documentation move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file.php) returns `TRUE` if everything went OK and `FALSE` if there was a problem.

So as you say, the image is not moving because move_uploaded_file is returning `FALSE`.
You can prove changing your code to this:

```
var_dump(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageUp"]["tmp_name"],
    "C:/xampp/htdocs/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]));
```

And seeing what is returning.

`move_uploaded_file` will return FALSE when:

1. The destination doesnt exists
2. The server doesnt have enough permissions to move the file to the destination
3. The file did not upload because it is bigger than the php.ini variable `upload_max_filesize`
4. The file did not upload because it is bigger than the php.ini variable `post_max_size`

Check and correct all those points and it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

The real reason why `unlink()` is executed is that you've disabled the if-condition

`if (file_exists($delete))` by using `//`.

here is the code, you may want to write:

```php
if (isset($_FILES["image"]["name"]) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],
        "C:/xampp/htdocs/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    if (file_exists($delete)) {
        unlink($delete);
    } else {
        $img = $data['row']->image_name;
    }
}
```

and make sure `$delete` is save! Imagine if `$delete` is equal to '`C:\users\your-name\some-private-file`'.
If you need more help, please give us more code sourrounding this snippet.